# Autoplay video in PhoneGap

Tags: ios5, cordova, html5-video

I have created a minimal PhoneGap app that has just this in the index.html:

```
<!-- ... -->
<body>
  <video src="test.m4v" autoplay onerror="alert('Error')"></video>
</body>
```

In the PhoneGap.plist I have set MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction to NO.

Yet I still cannot get the video to autoplay when the page loads. I have tried different ways of scripting it but to no avail.

Does anybody have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. Turned out to be a bug in PhoneGap 1.3 which was fixed in version 1.4 released yesterday(!).

From the [release notes](http://phonegap.com/2012/01/31/phonegap-1-4-released/):

> Fixed CB-42 – MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction can now be set to NO

Answer (score 2):

AutoPlay attribute work in ios :

```
  <video src="test.m4v" autoplay="autoplay"></video>
```

Given this line autoplay function

Answer (score 0):

"autoplay" attribute will not work in iOS so you need to use JavaScript to get it to play.

Here is some sample code:

```
var video = document.getElementById('someVideoId');
video.play();
```

Comment: Then it is probably something in Phonegap or something else that is wrong. Works fine for me on desktop and iOS. What happens when you try your code outside of Phonegap?