# HTML5 videos as splash screen for Sench Touch iOS App

Tags: javascript, ios, extjs, sencha-touch, html5-video

I wants to show a HTML5 video as splash screen for Sench Touch iOS App. I am using following code:

**Index.html:**

```
       <video id="splashScreen"  autoplay="autoplay" width="100%" height="100%" 
                            src="train.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function embedVideo() {
            var el = document.getElementById('splashScreen');
            el.src= "train.mp4";
            el.load();
        }
        </script>
```

And in **App.js:**

```
      launch: function() {

            var task = Ext.create('Ext.util.DelayedTask', function () {
                                  Ext.fly('splashScreen').destroy();
                                  });
            task.delay(4000);
            Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('TEC.view.Main'));
          }
```

It shows play controls that I don't want it to be shown and it also doesn't My next screen(Main) after 4 seconds as I want it to get destroyed after 4 secs.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Mobile devices will not allow you to auto play videos via the web/HTML.  User interaction is necessary to play videos on both iOS and Android.  I'm afraid your idea for a video splash screen is not possible (without user interaction) at this point.

If you wanted to wrap your mobile app in Phonegap, you could then autoplay your HTML videos:

[Autoplay video in PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9078098/autoplay-video-in-phonegap)